# custom listview not showing up in fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I was referring to a tutorial in androidhive.info and trying to join two examples, wherein i want to link the facebook type app with the navigation drawer example as shown in the website. 
Though I managed to merge the two examples however I am not getting the desired result.

1. I created a local server and accessing my local DB.
2. I am able to login. And I have changed my default fragment view to 2nd fragment which shows up kitchen.
3. However when i am pull out the drawer and click on the home, I end up getting my login screen. Please help me with this problem. I am quite new to android and I am not able to figure out anything.

Also do help me how can I improve my coding skills.

Below is my code where navigation drawer is being instantiated.

```
        package com.example.orderupdates;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.example.config.OrderUpdateConfig;
import com.example.model.NavDrawerItem;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "NavMenuTitles "+navMenuTitles);    


        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter

        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Adapter To be called");
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "ActionBar about to be called");
        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "ActionBar called and home button enabled");

        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "About to set mDrawerToggle");
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Closing Drawer !!!");
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Opening Drawer !!!");
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Display View Function to be called for 0th item");
            displayView(1);
        }
    }






    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Display view called");


        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {


        case 0:

            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Oth element Fragment");
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Oth element Fragment Manager About to be called");

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Begin transaction called");
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();


            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "DrawerList Is about to be set");


            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Set Title about to be called");

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);


            //setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "DrawerLayout About to be called");
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "DrawerLayout FINISHED");


        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

The layout file of the above code is as below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

The layout file for home fragment is here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The java file of the above fragment is as below :-

```
    package com.example.orderupdates;


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.example.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import com.example.app.AppController;
import com.example.config.OrderUpdateConfig;
import com.example.model.FeedItem;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

//  String[] AndroidOS = new String[] { "Cupcake","Donut","Eclair","Froyo","Gingerbread","Honeycomb","Ice Cream SandWich","Jelly Bean","KitKat" };
//  String[] Version = new String[]{"1.5","1.6","2.0-2.1","2.2","2.3","3.0-3.2","4.0","4.1-4.3","4.4"};

    private static final String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private com.example.adapter.FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<com.example.model.FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED="http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";
    private View rootView = null;

     public HomeFragment(){}

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
         Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Inside HOME FRAGMENT");
         return rootView;
    }

     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "Inside onActivityCreated ");

        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AndroidOS);
        //listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG, "FeedListAdapter to be called");
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter((HomeActivity)getActivity(), feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null){
            // fetch the data from cache
                        try {
                            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                            try {
                                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }else {

            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

        }
    }

     /**
         * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
         * */
        private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

                for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                    item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                    // Image might be null sometimes
                    String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                            .getString("image");
                    item.setImge(image);
                    item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                    item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                    item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                    // url might be null sometimes
                    String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                            .getString("url");
                    item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                    feedItems.add(item);
                }

                // notify data changes to list adapater
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump the whole code here - try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Noted .. I thought that would help me explain the entire problem

Comment: Have you checked the log? Does fragment transaction happens in switch condition?